# Select all rows in Table 1 and filling columns of Table 2

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables as follows:

Table1:

```
ID | FName | LName  
1  | A1    | A2  
2  | B1    | B2  
3  | C1    | C2
```

Table2:

```
ID | Price | Month | T1ID  
1  | 5     | 1     | 1  
2  | 5     | 1     | 2  
3  | 5     | 2     | 3
```

Result:
Where Month = '1'

```
ID  | FName | LName | Price | Month | T1ID  
1   | A1    | A2    | 5     | 1     | 1  
2   | B1    | B2    | 5     | 1     | 2  
NULL| C1    | C2    | NULL  | NULL  | 3
```

Where Month = '2'

```
ID  | FName | LName | Price | Month | T1ID  
NULL| A1    | A2    | NULL  | NULL  | 1  
NULL| B1    | B2    | NULL  | NULL  | 2  
3   | C1    | C2    | 5     | 2     | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a left join with multiple join conditions:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t1.FName, t1.LName, t2.Price, t2.Month, t1.ID
FROM Table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.T1ID AND t2.Month = '1' -- or '2'
```

The trick is to do filtering by adding additional condition to `ON` clause, which helps to filter records during the join. If you used the condition in `WHERE` clause, some records would be filtered out from the results, which is not what you expect.